# Text editor with synchronized scrolling and spell check features

Tags: text-editor, spell-checking, synchronized

I'm looking for a text editor that have these 2 features available:
- Synchronized scrolling: You can have 2 tabs, side by side and you scroll both at the same time.
- Spell check as you type (highlight, underline word, spell check on the fly)
I have currently been using Notepad++ exactly because of this feature of Synchronized Scrolling, however the spell checking support is weak.
I wouldn't mind even finding a word processor with these features, as my main use for synchronized scrolling is for translating texts, having both language texts on display.

I'll be glad for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the Windows platform, the [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) editor has the *Synchronized Scrolling* option (i.e. found on the Windows menu) but it does not have the *dynamic spell checking* feature.

The spell checking in Zeus is *user initiated* (i.e Spelling menu) and not dynamic.

NOTE: Zeus is *shareware* but there is also a *freeware* [Zeus Lite](http://www.zeusedit.com/lite) version that has these the same two features.